# Error: urn:acme:error:rateLimited :: There were too many requests of a given type

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to obtain a Let's Encrypt Certificate through xip.io. Whenever I try it I get the following error:

Error: urn:acme:error:rateLimited :: There were too many requests of a given type

I've read that this happens because there's a limit to 5 certs every 7 days per domain. This is the first time I've tried doing this though. Is there any way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the forums and github documentation for letsencrypt that I have read, to work around this, if you are testing, you should point it to the staging server.

```
class { ::letsencrypt:
  config => {
    email  => 'foo@example.com',
    server => 'https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory',
  }
}
```